# On typing a query, each alphabet is producing new single page. How it should be prevented?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

I'm working, a project in which I have to create a search engine. I'm facing problem, whenever a user types a query for each and every alphabet typed a new page is being reproduced. For example if I type - 'fos' , 3 pages are being produced. If I type 'fossa' 5 pages are being produced. 
[image]

I have used redux architecture and angular 2 in my project. How should I solve this problem ? Thanks in advance :)

```
onquery(event: any) {
   if (event.target.value.length > 2) {
     this.store.dispatch(new query.QueryAction(event.target.value));
     this.displayStatus = 'showbox';
     this.submit();
     this.hidebox(event);
    }
  }
submit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/search'], {queryParams: this.searchdata});
}
```

HTML

```
<input #input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" id="nav-input" (keyup)="onquery($event)"
           [(ngModel)]="searchdata.query" autocomplete="off">
```

Reducer code -

```
export const CHANGE = 'CHANGE';

export interface State {
  searchresults: any;
  items: any;
}

const initialState: State = {
  searchresults: {},
  items: []
};

export function reducer(state: State = initialState, action: search.Actions): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case search.ActionTypes.CHANGE: {
      const search = action.payload;
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        searchresults: search,
        items: search.channels[0].items
      });
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate add some code. Are you typing into a textbox in angular 2 project which is supposed to be doing an http call to a server to retrieve the serach results and display in a drop down of the search box?

Comment: @VinayPrabhakaran I have updated my question with code. There is `onquery()` function which will be called whenever a query is typed in.

Comment: @Harshit I have tried to answer your question in a generic way. But please revise your question IMO it is not really clear. Thanks!

Comment: show us reducer code, are you doing a `pushState` on every key stroke ?
 use [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) instead

Comment: @Faris I have updated my question with reducer code.

Comment: @Faris I'm not using `pushState` nor `replaceState` . I have provided the code. Check `onquery()` function. With `dispatch()` I'm not using them. I'm new to redux. It would be great if you can help me out :)

Comment: oh wait, it must be your submit function, what does it do?

Comment: @Faris Updated my question. Added `submit()` with `onquery()` function. The `submit()` functions navigate to `/search` reducer.

Comment: ready my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `onquery` on every keyup

`onquery` is calling `submit`

`submit` is calling `router.navigate` which is indeed navigating! (thus pushing to browser history as you show in your screenshot)

why do you want to navigate to search page while user is still typing?

you should call the `submit` function on `ngSubmit` placed on your `form` element like so

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <input #input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" id="nav-input" (keyup)="onquery($event)"
           [(ngModel)]="searchdata.query" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Comment: One thing, `sumbit()` was working as instant search feature. Now it is not working after removing it from `onquery()` . Is there any other solution for it also without disturbing instant search feature ? Although I get results when I hit enter key.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is about: how to limit calling of a function (which create a new page) for each keystroke when user typing. You should consider using debounce or throttle.

> Debounce and throttle are two similar (but different!) techniques to
>   control how many times we allow a function to be executed over time.

Here an example in jQuery as a start, be aware you need to adapt it for your angular app:

https://gist.github.com/makenova/7885923

Useful:
https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function